# CentOS init scripts dependencies

Tags: centos

How do I specify dependencies between init scripts on CentOS?

E.g. I need that when service "tomcat" is started it first start service "soffice".

On Gentoo we can do:

```
depend() {
  need soffice
}
```

But what about CentOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CentOS out of the box uses an integer to specify the start/stop.

If you look inside an init script you'll most likely see: `chkconfig: - 85 15`

First number:  start priority (higher = lower priority)

Second:  Stop priority (lower = lower priority)

If you hop into `/etc/rc3.d` (or depending on run level).

Files start with either an `S` (start) or a `K` (kill, stop) followed by an integer.  Same concept applies in regards to numerics.

In some cases you'll see: `chkconfig: - 2345 85 15`

To change order, simply adjust those numbers.

This simply represents the run levels (2,3,4,5).

Comment: After changing the order you still need to (re)-add: chkconfig <service> off ; chkconfig <service> on

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think S is stands for Start and K is stands for Kill

Answer (score 2):

There's a section in init script:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
....
### END INIT INFO
```

Probably you'll need something like this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          tomcat
# Required-Start:    $network
# Required-Stop:     $network
# Default-Start:     3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Start-Before:    soffice
# Short-Description: xxxx
# Description:       xxxx
### END INIT INFO
```

More info:
https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

After modifying this section you should disable and then enable tomcat service again:

```
chkconfig --del tomcat
chkconfig --add tomcat
```

Comment: Does CentOS 6 support this? Their documentation does not mention using LSB when writing init scripts. (`/usr/share/doc/initscripts-9.03.40/sysvinitfiles`)